# Access control to names of members in C++

Tags: c++

While reading *The C++ Programming Language* by Bjarne Stroustrup, there's a few sentences that i have trouble getting a sense of. The paragraph, which is right below, is about access control to members of a class in C++ such as private, protected, public. The **bold** words are referring to a specific concept, which i have no idea what that is.

> The access control is applied uniformly to names. **What a name refers to** does not affect the control of **its** use. This means that we can have private member functions, types, constants, etc., as well as private data members.

My best assumption is that "What a name refers to" stands for an object in raw memory, which ultimately means that we can take a pointer to an object entity of private member in raw memory, and access it regardless of access control. However, it seems to be wrong considering that it has nothing to do with the statement that we can have private members. I have no idea what the paragraph above tries to convey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what he meant:

Let's say you have a *private member* named `p_member`. Of course, it can be a **data member**, a **method**, a **constant**... but in the context of access control, the nature of `p_member` does not play a significant role. What is important is that the member named `p_member` is private. Doesn't matter if it's a data member or a method - it is equally private.

Comment: It's very difficult to select the one from many answers which are equally nice. Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand it such a way that the key explanation is in the next sentence:

> This means that we can have private member functions, types,
>   constants, etc., as well as private data members

That is it is unimportant what a name defines. The access control is applied to all kinds of definitions in a class whether it is a definition of a data member, or a member function or a definition of some type etc.